# Why the VS2019 that installed the latest Qt Addin does not have the Qt project template?

Tags: visual-studio, qt

I installed the latest VS2019 commnity , and then installed  the latest Qt Addin plugin into it. 
I built the latest Qt5.13.1 with VS2019 , and configured the Qt Addin with the output.

But the VS2019's new project/solution still dones NOT have the qt project template .

There is also a very strange thing : VS2019 loaded a VS2013+Qt5.7 solution into it and build it successfully , then any small change in one .cpp file will lead all the solution to be rebuilt. build operation become rebuild operation.

Comment: I have the exact same problem on two different computers.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstall the VS2019, and the Qt project template show up.

I reconstruct my project , and the build procession becomes normal.